# Span of finite dimensional complex representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I have a homework question that asks me to do the following:

Let $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ be a simple finite dimensional complex representation. Show that
$$\text{Span}_{\mathbb{C}}\{\rho(g)\ |\ g \in G\} = \text{End}_{\mathbb{C}}V$$

I'm clueless about how to begin. I'll be glad if someone can provide with an hints or references I'll figure out what to do.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\End{\operatorname{End}}$
It sort of depends on what you know (both in the sense of what background you personally have, and what you know about the group and the representation.)

Let $A = \operatorname{Span}\{\rho(g): g \in G\}$.

You can apply special considerations if the group is finite or the representation is unitary.

In general ($G$ not necessarily finite, $\rho$ not necessarily unitary) $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra acting faithfully and irreducibly on a finite dimensional vector space $V$.  It follows that $A$ is also semisimple, because the radical is killed in a (semi)simple representation. So you can apply Wedderburn theory/Jacobsen density theorem to $A$.

Or, the short answer is this is Cor. 3.5 on page 649 of Lang, Algebra,revised 3rd edition.